# How to retrieve zipcode and mobile number from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to retrieve user's mobile number and zipcode in facebook graph api. I am using the below mentioned permission.

```
PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"publish_stream", "offline_access", "user_birthday", "email", "user_location" };
```

Can anyone give me some idea how to retrieve this two things (zipcode and mobile number) ?

Comment: Are you getting response? Have you tried to parse and get value from response?

Comment: I am not getting these two values in response. Is any other permission required to retrieve that.

Comment: As what i know it is not possible to retrieve user mobile number from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can **never** retrieve the Mobile number of a Facebook user through the API as it is not exposed through any of the present API.

Secondly when you can query for the zip code using fql

```
select current_location from user where uid=me()
```

Though at times the zip field may be just blank. You don't need any extra permissions for it.

Comment: what is the extra permission ?

Comment: @user2106413 You don't need any more, `user_location` permission would get you the user's current location along with the zip code. But as I said it might be empty.